# parameter error in python script & TOR proxy server

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, tor, proxy-server

I am Noob in Python. **My Boss instructed me to run this python script with TOR proxy server running.**  He told me to pass this parameter this way: 
python DownloadYP.py /Users/myfolder/ japan http://www.jpyellow.com/company 1 222299

He configured it on MAC. I am using windows. So my parameter is this way:
python DownloadYP.py C:\rrrb japan http://www.jpyellow.com/company 1 222299

But I am getting error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\yp1\code\DownloadYP.py", line 92, in <module>
WebPage(path, country, url, lowerlimit,upperlimit)
File "C:\Users\USER\yp1\code\DownloadYP.py", line 23, in __init__
fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\rrr/japan/limit.txt'
```

**My Code is:**

- DownloadYP.py

  ```
  def __init__(self, path, country, url, lower=0,upper=9999):
      self.dir = str(path)+"/"+ str(country)
      self.url = url
      try:
        fin = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'r')
          limit = fin.readline()
          limits = str(limit).split(",")
          lower = int(limits[0])
          upper = int(limits[1])
          fin.close()
      except:
  ```

  ## this is line 23

  ```
            **fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')**
          limits = str(lower)+","+str(upper)
          fout.write(limits)
          fout.close()  
      self.process_instances(lower,upper)


      def process_instances(self,lower,upper):
              try:
                  os.stat(self.dir)
              except:
                  os.mkdir(self.dir)
              for count in range(lower,upper+1):
                  if count == upper:
                      print "all downloaded, quitting the app!!"
                      break
                  targetURL = self.url+"/"+str(count)
                  print "Downloading :" + targetURL
                  req = urllib2.Request(targetURL)
                  try:
                      response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                      the_page = response.read()  
                      if the_page.find("Your IP suspended")>=0:
                          print "The IP is suspended"
                          fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
                          limits = str(count)+","+str(upper)
                          fout.write(limits)
                          fout.close()  
                          break
                      if the_page.find("Too many requests")>=0:
                          print "Too many requests"
                          print "Renew IP...."
                          fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
                          limits = str(count)+","+str(upper)
                          fout.write(limits)
                          fout.close()
                          break


  #subprocess.Popen("sudo  /Users/myfolder/Documents/workspace/DataMining/ip_renew.py", shell=True)
                      if the_page.find("404 error")>=0:
                          print "the page not exist"
                          continue
                      self.saveHTML(count, the_page)
                  except:
                      print "The URL cannot be fetched"
                      pass
                      #raise

      def saveHTML(self,count, content):
          fout = open(self.dir+"/"+str(count)+".html",'wb')
          fout.write(content)
          fout.close()

      if __name__ == '__main__':

      if len(sys.argv) !=6:
          print "cannot process!!! Five Parameters are required to run the          process."
          print "Parameter 1 should be the path where to save the data, eg, /Users/myfolder/data/"
          print "Parameter 2 should be the name of the country for which data is collected, eg, japan"
          print "Parameter 3 should be the URL from which the data to collect, eg, http://www.jpyellow.com/company/"
          print "Parameter 4 should be the lower limit of the company id, eg, 11 "
          print "Parameter 5 should be the upper limit of the company id, eg, 1000 "
          print "The output will be saved as the HTML file for each company in the target folder's country"
          exit()
      else:
          path = str(sys.argv[1])
          country = str(sys.argv[2])
          url = str(sys.argv[3])
          lowerlimit = int(sys.argv[4])
          upperlimit = int(sys.argv[5])
  ```

  ## This is LINE 92

  ```
          **WebPage(path, country, url, lowerlimit,upperlimit)**
  ```

I have downloaded TorVPN to run a Proxy server.. and running this script. So why the error is occurring? This is the script which can download a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `DownloadYP.py` -

You do not have the files - `C:\\rrr\japan\limit.txt`

I would suggest creating a dummy file in the above directory with that name, and try running the script again.

Also, on a side note - You are mixing the os path separaters from unix and using it in windows , instead you need to use `os.path.join()` function so that python is able to handle the os path separaters accross platforms. The code would be like -

```
import os
self.dir = os.path.join(str(path),str(country))
```

Also, when openning the file, you need to use `os.path.join` , instead of directly specifying the path separators -

```
fin = open(os.path.join(self.dir,"limit.txt"),'r')
```